# In my sqlite database, I want to store date as '01.02.13' instead of '2013-02-01', is that possible?

Tags: sqlite, date

`SELECT date('now');` prints `YYYY-MM-DD`, i want it reversed.

`SELECT strftime('%d.%m.%Y','now');` prints `DD.MM.YYYY`, and I want to have only 2 digits in year.

How to sort by date and group by year with this format?

Comment: Unfortunately no, sqlite [only supports `YYYY`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); but what is the problem with the four digit year? Why do you want it as two digit?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It's not very important, i asked just to be sure.

Comment: Make sure you distinguish between how SQLite *stores* a date, and how it *displays* the date. You are asking about the latter, not the former.

Comment: Rethink your requirements. `YYYY-MM-DD` is a better format. It's an [ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it's unambiguous, and it sorts nicely. In the US, dates are commonly formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YY`; is `01.02.13` January 2 or February 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow the date to be stored in 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Let's focus on how to display the date in the format you desire. chepner's comment is quite valuable.

Let's take a table like so:

```
name        dob
----------  ----------
John        1990-12-31
Sarah       1989-12-31
Thelma      1989-11-30
Matt        1990-11-30
```

Let's display a 2-character year also:

```
sqlite> select a.*, substr(strftime('%Y', dob),3, 2) as yr from test a;
name        dob         yr
----------  ----------  ----------
John        1990-12-31  90
Sarah       1989-12-31  89
Thelma      1989-11-30  89
Matt        1990-11-30  90
```

Let's display date in dd.mm.yyyy format and dd.mm.yy format:

```
sqlite> select a.*,
   ...> strftime('%d.%m.', dob) || substr(strftime('%Y', dob),3, 2) as yr,
   ...> strftime('%d.%m.%Y', dob) as moddob
   ...> from test a;
name        dob         yr          moddob
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
John        1990-12-31  31.12.90    31.12.1990
Sarah       1989-12-31  31.12.89    31.12.1989
Thelma      1989-11-30  30.11.89    30.11.1989
Matt        1990-11-30  30.11.90    30.11.1990
```

Let's find out how many were born in different years:

```
sqlite> select substr(strftime('%Y', dob), 3, 2) as yr,
   ...> count(*)
   ...> from test
   ...> group by yr;
yr          count(*)
----------  ----------
89          2
90          2
```

Let's find out how many were born in different months:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%m', dob) as mth,
   ...> count(*)
   ...> from test
   ...> group by mth;
mth         count(*)
----------  ----------
11          2
12          2
```